# Custom layout per navigation item

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, selected

Hi i want to make two items to have a CustomLayout and the other to retain the initialLayout.My  question is there a better way then to use fragments for every item.

My code looks like this

```
if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 0){

            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, timePickerFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 1)
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, initialFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 2)
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, initialFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 3)
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager3 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, initialFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }  else if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 4)
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager4 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, datePickerFragmen);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }  else if(actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() == 5)
            android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager5 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction5 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, initialFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not you notice that you have duplication code 6 times?

```
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, /* Put here fragment variable generated by your defined conditions */);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: if i use the code snippet you provided only once then all of my items will have that layout, and i don't want that , i want a different layout on every item in that actionbar

Comment: You have if/break/return and other instructions in Java language. You also might did not read a comment `Put here fragment variable generated by your defined conditions` so fragments would be different

Comment: sorry, now i get it, it's late here, thanks a lot for your time and pacience.